# Using bjam's pythonpath feature

Tags: python, boost, boost-python, bjam

I have a Jamfile that I am using with Boost.Python to wrap some C++ classes. I have the Jamfile automatically running a python script and loading the extension as a post-compile step:

```
rule run-test ( test-name : sources + )
{
    import testing ;
    testing.make-test run-pyd : $(sources) : : $(test-name) ;
}
```

Then:

```
PROJECT_NAME = example ;
run-test $(PROJECT_NAME) : $(PROJECT_NAME)_ext test_$(PROJECT_NAME)_ext.py ;
```

This would build example_ext.so, then run test_example_ext.py which does a simple "import example_ext" and then some basic testing.

The problem is that I need test_example_ext.py to be able to import some Python modules from other packages, so I need to set PYTHONPATH. From the command-line, this isn't a problem, but bjam doesn't appear to carry this through to its spawned Python process, even if exported.

In this case I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=..
```

I.e. setting the Python search path one level above where I am running bjam.

The closest I've managed to [get](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/patch-for-PYTHONPATH-in-bpl-test-td2692178.html) is to work out that this does what I want:

```
$ bjam pythonpath=..
```

This actually works. But I want to set this in the Jamfile, not rely on the command line. I've read the bjam manual which says that this is a *property* and I can use `<pythonpath>..` somewhere. But it doesn't say where.

So my problem is that I can't work out how to specify this *property* in a Jamfile. Where does it go? What's the syntax? Is it part of "import python ;", or "using python ..." in user-config.jam, or part of the run-pyd or even the python-extension rule? I've tried all these randomly without understanding or success.

In `boost_1_50_0/tools/build/v2/tools/python.jam` I found:

> # The pythonpath feature specifies additional elements for the PYTHONPATH
>   # environment variable, set by run-pyd. For example, pythonpath can be used to
>   # access Python modules that are part of the product being built, but are not
>   # installed in the development system's default paths.
>   **feature.feature pythonpath : : free optional path ;**

That appears to be declaring the 'pythonpath' property (aka feature), but for what context? Where and how can it be used?

And [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/bbv2/extender.html#bbv2.extending.features) page demonstrates how to define a property along those lines, but not really how or where to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I may have found an answer to my own question.

The solution appears to be the `project` rule below, with the `requirements` keyword, although I haven't yet understood why it works, or the implications of specifying this.

Here's my Jamfile:

```
PROJECT_NAME = example ;

import python ;

# sets PYTHONPATH when executing run-test
project : requirements <pythonpath>.. ;

python-extension $(PROJECT_NAME)_ext :
  $(PROJECT_NAME).cpp
  $(PROJECT_NAME)_ext.cpp
:
;

# Declare test targets
run-test $(PROJECT_NAME) : $(PROJECT_NAME)_ext test_$(PROJECT_NAME)_ext.py ;
```

For completeness, I actually have this picking up a Jamroot file one directory up, that looks like this:

```
import python ;

# Specify the path to the Boost project.  If you move this project,
# adjust this path to refer to the Boost root directory.
use-project boost
  : ./boost ;

# Set up the project-wide requirements that everything uses the
# boost_python library from the project whose global ID is
# /boost/python.
project
  : requirements <library>/boost/python//boost_python ;

# A little "rule" (function) to clean up the syntax of declaring tests
# of these extension modules.
rule run-test ( test-name : sources + )
{
    import testing ;
    testing.make-test run-pyd : $(sources) : : $(test-name) ;
}
```